# How can i make Rectangle Image in JavaFX to use as Treeview Icon

Tags: image, javafx, imageview, javafx-8

I am just making an Treeview in JavaFX. And i want to make Treeview Icon as rectangle shape just filled with color.
How can i make Rectangle shaped imageview for Treeview`s icon?

I just want to do like this...

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(20,20,20,20);
r.setFill(Color.BLACK);
Image mImage = new Image("I want to use r object here..");
ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(mImage);
```

Or the other way to make Rectangle shaped Imageview in code.

Comment: Just create the `Rectangle` and set it as the `TreeItem`'s graphic. If you really want to use an `ImageView`, you can create a `WriteableImage` and fill it using its `PixelWriter`.

Comment: To display a rectangular image you could play around with the `fitWidth`, `fitHeight`, `preserveRatio` and `viewPort` properties. There are also `Image` constructors scaling the `Image`. About the rest of the question: I'm not sure about the desired output: Do you want to display an `ImageView` as `graphic` next to the arrow or replace the arrow with the image?

Comment: @Slaw Thanks, I didn`t know that i can use Rectangle as graphic.

Comment: Yep. `TreeItem`s graphic property holds a `Node`, which `Rectangle` inherits from.

Comment: @fabian Thank you, Actually i just want to add rectangle image as icon not replace the arrow image. and just using setGraphic(rectangle) worked. :)